# After login pull data for respective users from db

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

M building a web app here.The authentication php code looks like this  (Please ignore the threats for time being) :

```html
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 mysql_connect('localhost','*****','******') or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db('cl29-demodb') or die(mysql_error());
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $pwd=$_POST['password'];
 if($name!='' && $pwd!='')
 {
   $query=mysql_query("select * from EmployeeTable where EmployeeName ='".$name."' and password='".$pwd."'") or die(mysql_error());
   $res=mysql_fetch_row($query);
   if($res)
   {
     $_SESSION['id']=$res['id'];

 header('location: profileindex.php');
   }
   else
   {
    echo "user name and password are incorrect" ;
 echo "<a href=index.php> click here to go back </a>";
   }
 }
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
echo "Sorry, Please login and use this page";
exit;
}
}
?>
```

I am able to login successfully and reach the profile of the user.But I want the profile to display only the information for respective users.The profile looks like this:
[image: profile snap]

I have written the php to retrive the name,designation,weekly points,overall points,weekly rank and overall rank respectively.
[image: php to pull data]

I tried to echo the variables in the html.
But I am not able to do so.It isnot pulling any data.I have column for all the above fields in the table.
[image]

Kindly help.

Comment: arent you having any error ?

Comment: I am not able to retrieve any data from the db for the user who logIn..@RaniMorelesRubillos

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Please post code here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Thanks for the input.I understand the threats.I will work on them.But for time being m trying to pull the data from the db.I will chnage the pic to codes.Thanks

Comment: sorry for the late response try to use this instead of mysqli_fetch_array but if you would use array you need to get the rows by their index not by column name so try this one mysqli_fetch_assoc

Comment: Do a `print_r();` of `$row` and see what you get back from the database. If it's empty something is wrong with either the connection or the query. If it's filled you will know what variables to use to display them. Alternatively echo some random strings along your program to see how far it actually gets to run. Sometimes I make mistakes on my if-else statements and this is a good indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this is the cause 
`mysql_fetch_row()` return the numeric array and you are accessing as `$res['id']`

either replace `mysql_fetch_row` with `mysql_fetch_array` or try numeric index of your id

```
$_SESSION['id']=$res[0]; or $_SESSION['id']=$res[1];
```

Comment: Thanks but no luck

Comment: @Shivam did you try `echo $_SESSION['id'] ; die()` in authentication php code

Comment: Thanks I solved the issue with your above asked changes.God bless.

Comment: happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

use mysqli_fetch_assoc so you could call the columns by name if you are using mysql_fetch_array you should call the columns by their index no the by the column name.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to start a session again in the profileindex.php as the session has already started in the login page.

print the sql and run it in the backend to check if you are getting the desired result in order to further debug this.

Comment: Thanks but that session start is necessary

Comment: You only need to start the session once and it already started before the authentication code so no need to start it again

Comment: This is not true.You need session_start in every page you using sessions. So for this point @ShivamSharma is correct.